# Saving multiple addresses as JSON array in Parse.com

Tags: android, arrays, json, parse-platform

I have an e-commerce based app in which the User can store one or more addresses and have their items shipped to them. The address is input as 1)Name, 2) Address Line1, 3)Address line 2, 4)City, 5)Pin Code. In order to store the address as these 5 separate entities, I make use of JSON

```
public JSONObject convert() {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("name", "Varun Agarwal");
        jsonObject.put("number", "+91-9*********");

        JSONObject jsonAddr = new JSONObject();
        jsonAddr.put("address1", "Floor Number, Building Name");
        jsonAddr.put("address2", "Locality and Landmarks");
        jsonAddr.put("city", "Mumbai");

        jsonObject.put("address", jsonAddr);

        Log.d("sample json made ", jsonObject.toString());
        return jsonObject;

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

So as of now I am saving this as a JSON object in parse

```
{
    "name":"Varun Agarwal",
    "number":"+91-9*********",
    "address":{
        "address1":"Floor Number, Building Name" ,
        "address2":"Locality and Landmarks",
        "city":"Mumbai"
    }
}
```

If the user wants to save more than one address at a time then I would need to keep defining more columns called Address1, Address2, Address3 etc. Instead I tried using JSON array something like this

```
[
  {
    "id":"1",
    "address":"{.....}"
  },
  {
    "id":"2",
    "address":"{.....}"
  },
  {
    "id":"3",
    "address":"{.....}"
  }
]
```

I have been struggling with the logic and my questions are

1) Am I on the right track or is there a much better of doing the same?

2) I know how to add JSON objects to an array but when querying them, how do I make sure I am calling the right one?

3)How would I go about deleting or changing one of the addresses, say User removes address id:2 and adds a new one after that. Or he simply changes one of the values in a particular address id

4) The other option I thought of was to make a new class called Addresses, store all of them there and everytime a user saves a new address, I create a new "Address" row and simply reference it via an array of pointers. Is this viable?

Comment: I think the last option is better for your situation. Either that or simply store the address entries directly on the User object.

Comment: By the way no need to reference each row if you create an Address class, a single pointer User -> Address will do. Then you can easily query and modify the columns of address information without any problems.  Hmm won't let me delete the comment, but of course if you expect multiple addresses, an array of pointers makes sense.

Comment: So an array of pointers for the user which points to an Address Class. Is i reach say 100,000 or even 1million users, will that be an issue with the database as it will be sooo big. Say each user has 3-4 address, wont that slow down the app? Im not used to dealing with databses hence the question.

Comment: As long as each individual user does not have more than 100 addresses, that design would continue to be efficient. Each user entry (as all other objects) are indexed by their unique objectId, so locating the address of a particular user should be the same whether you have 1 or 1 million users (more or less)

Comment: Another equally fit solution would be to store an 'owner' pointer on each address pointing to the user who created it. This way you do not need to have the array of address pointers on the User object. Simply query all Address objects matching the current user. Just to give you a third option of implementation.

Comment: Ya that's true but if I use the array I can use the include feature which it much better.  Performance wise owner pointer in address or storing as array of pointers on user column makes a difference? I just saw that parse can't ha

Comment: Seems like you finish writing in the last comment. But yes that is true, the include feature removes the need for a second query.